# Is there a definition of the "boundary" of a simplicial complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

Let $S$ be the abstract simplicial complex with facets $\{A,B,D\}$, $\{A,C,D\}$, $\{B,C,D\}$. Its geometric representation is homeomorphic to a disc:

[image]

In this picture, the geometric representation of the sub-complex $T$ with facets $\{A,B\}$, $\{B,C\}$, $\{C,A\}$ maps to the boundary of the disc. So we can say that "the boundary of $S$ is $T$".

My question is: is this notion of "boundary" well-defined?
That is, given any abstract complex $S$ with geometric representation homeomorphic to a ball, is there a *unique* subcomplex $T\subseteq S$, such that the geometric representation of $T$ equals the boundary of that ball?

Comment: Your "Particularly" question — which has a positive answer — is not a particular question of your main question, as there is no such thing as the boundary of an abstract simplicial complex.

Comment: _If_ your first simplex is **pure** (i.e. all maximal elements are finite of the same size $n$), and _if_ all sub-simplices of size $n-1$ are shared by at most 2 maximal simplices, then you _could_ define the boundary as those sub-simplices of size $n-1$ that are shared by strictly less than 2 maximal subsimplices. But that's a lot of ifs

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I edited the question to clarify that I am mainly interested in complexes with geometric representation homeomorphic to a ball.

Comment: @student91 don't these conditions follow from the requirement that the geometric representation of $S$ is homeomorphic to a ball?

Comment: Yes it does, but then why don't you work with geometric simplical complexes instead of abstract simplical complexes to begin with?

Comment: @student91 because the application I am interested in is combinatorial, so I need abstract complexes

Answer (score 1):

You *could* define it as follows:

Let $S$ be an abstract simplical complex. Then define $\partial S=\{A\in S\colon \exists!B\in S, A\subsetneq B\}$ where $\exists!$ means "There is a unique".

The idea behind this definition is as follows:

- If there is *no* $B\supseteq A$, then $A$ is maximal/part of the "body" of the complex, and the boundary should be part of this $A$, not $A$ itself.
- If there is more than one $B\supseteq A$, then $A$ is either "too small", i.e. there are $A\subseteq B\subseteq B'$, or $A$ is on the "boundary" of two $B$, i.e. there are $B$, $B'$ with $B\cap B'=A$.

But I do not know if this definition is standard.

You can then try to prove all properties you require.

Comment: This definition makes sense, but I am not sure how to prove that, in every geometric realization of $S$, this set is indeed mapped to the boundary.

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi you would first have to make clear what you mean with "boundary". e.g. if you embed a ball $D^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^4$, the topological boundary $\partial D^3=\overline{D^3}\setminus (D^3)^\circ$ would be the complete ball, so you can't use that. What definition of boundary do you use? Or do you use some adjusted form of the boundary from the singular homology definition?